# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #6](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/6) on English Language & Usage has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Laurel]

[image: NVZ]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Matt E. Эллен, who's been serving as a moderator since the 2014 election, and will be stepping down from the role:

[image: Matt E. Эллен]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/6) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5949294306656256).

Comment: Congratulations to the winners.

Comment: Once again, EL&U was very fortunate to have more highly qualified candidates than open positions in this election. I'm sure that NVZ and Laurel will be excellent moderators—but I also want to thank Lawrence and Jesse Steele for throwing their hats in the ring. All four candidates made strong cases for themselves with their thoughtful responses to the pre-election questionnaire, and all deserve our gratitude.

Comment: It is always pleasant to feel that people appointed  to a job will do it better than I could have done it myself had I tried. And so I congratulate both winners.

Comment: Many thanks to Matt for his  measured and friendly modship and other non-modish contributions!

Comment: Thanks @SvenYargs, and congratulations to NVZ and Laurel. Thanks Jesse Steel for kicking off the elections as the first to nominate, and Matt for carrying the mod mantle well. Also a big shout out to our continuing mods who are continuing to put in time and effort behind the scenes, especially those such as Kit Z. Fox who have been doing this for the longest time - you've set a good tone for our fresh mods.

Comment: Thank you all for the vote and support. I'm happy to be here!

Answer (score 12):

Congratulations and welcome to our new moderators ♦! Looking forward to your extended contribution to EL&U. Best of luck, Laurel and NVZ!

Thank you, Matt, for your exceptional service. We'll miss you as a moderator, but I hope you stick around (those quality answers won't write themselves).

Lawrence and Jesse, thank you for putting yourselves out there. You were both good candidates with years of experience (inside EL&U and outside too) and I hope you consider running again in a future election.